# Compile all less file using a makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a number of less file that I would like to compile using a makefile.

```
DEBUG=yes
LESS_FILES= static/backend/css/styles.less static/frontend/css/styles.less

ifeq ($(DEBUG),yes)
    LESSC=lessc
else
    LESSC=lessc -x
endif


less: $(LESS_FILES)

%.css: %.less
    $(LESSC) $< > $@
```

I created this makefile, but when starting `make less` I get :

```
make: Rien à faire pour « less ».
```

The file `.css` doesn't exists yet. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've got it ! Sometimes it's help to ask the question to find the answer ...

```
DEBUG=True
LESS_FILES= static/admin/css/modulo_admin.less
CSS_FILES=$(LESS_FILES:.less=.css)

ifeq ($(DEBUG),True)
    LESSC=lessc
else
    LESSC=lessc -x
endif

less: $(CSS_FILES)

%.css: %.less
    $(LESSC) $< > $@
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the target `less` depends upon the *source* files. Those already exist and are up-to-date.

I suggest changing the `less` target to look more like this:

```
less: $(CSS_FILES:.less=.css)
```

(Untested, I don't have the `lessc` tool installed, nor suitable input files.)